# How to load from memory stream to firemonkey (FMX) memo component in C++ Builder Berlin?

Tags: c++, c++builder, firemonkey

I used to use below code to load plenty of text to VCL Memo.

```
LogMemo->Lines->BeginUpdate();
LogMemo->SelStart = LogMemo->GetTextLen();
LogMemo->SelLength = 0;

LogMemo->SelText = AnsiString((char *)LogMemoBufPtr->Memory, LogMemoBufPtr->Size);
LogMemo->SelStart = LogMemo->GetTextLen();
LogMemo->Perform(EM_SCROLLCARET, 0, 0);
LogMemo->Lines->EndUpdate();
```

But in FMX Memo component, I can't use "LogMemo->SelText = AnsiString(strFromMemStream)" anymore.
And I also can't use "GetTextLen" method to set selection start.

I tried to modify the code in below but it still didn't work. It always overwrite original content and can't append new text.

```
LogMemo->Lines->BeginUpdate();
LogMemo->GoToTextEnd();
LogMemo->SelStart = LogMemo->Text.Length();
LogMemo->SelLength = 0;

LogMemo->Text = AnsiString((char *)LogMemoBufPtr->Memory, LogMemoBufPtr->Size);
LogMemo->GoToTextEnd();
LogMemo->SelStart = LogMemo->Text.Length();
LogMemoBufPtr->Clear();
LogMemo->Lines->EndUpdate();
```

Is there any one know how to do it in FMX Memo component or just to display plenty of text smoothly?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you define what is `LogMemoBufPtr` ?

Comment: In the first example, `LogMemo->SelText = AnsiString(...)` will add the new text at the end of the `LogMemo->Text` and in the second example, `LogMemo->Text = AnsiString(...)` will overwrite the existing text. So, what feature do you need ?

Comment: LogMemoBufPtr is a pointer of "TMemoryStream" for storing text. I know "LogMemo->Text" will overwrite all existing text. But in FMX Memo component, I can't use "SelText = AnsiString(...)". That's why I tried to find other way to put text into Text. All I expect is to append more text to memo quickly. The first example is I used for VCL component. But I can't use the same code in FMX component. I need to write cross-platform application. So, I must use FMX components.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [SetText](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/FMX.Memo.TCustomMemo.Text) function or [Lines](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/FMX.Memo.TCustomMemo.Lines) property.

In both cases I think you will have to convert the ASCII text to Unicode first.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've tried to use "Lines->LoadFromStream" but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1** - Based to the second source code provided, here is a solution to append a text in the `TMemo` object in FMX/FireMonkey Library.

**Step 1** - Instead of trying to place the cursor and select the end of the text.

> Before:

```
LogMemo->GoToTextEnd();
LogMemo->SelStart = LogMemo->Text.Length();
LogMemo->SelLength = 0;
```

Select all the text and store it in a temporary string.

> After:

```
System::UnicodeString suTemp;

LogMemo->Lines->BeginUpdate();
LogMemo->GoToTextEnd();
LogMemo->SelStart = 0;
LogMemo->SelLength = LogMemo->Text.Length();
suTemp = LogMemo->SelText;
```

**Step 2** - Then append the new text to the temporary string and update the Memo

```
suTemp += AnsiString((char *)LogMemoBufPtr->Memory, LogMemoBufPtr->Size);
LogMemo->Text = suTemp;
LogMemo->GoToTextEnd();
LogMemo->SelStart = LogMemo->Text.Length();
LogMemoBufPtr->Clear();
LogMemo->Lines->EndUpdate();
```

**Solution 2** - Simple and faster solution when add the text at the end.

> Store the current text into a temporary string and add the new text
>   then update the memo.

```
System::UnicodeString suTemp;

LogMemo->Lines->BeginUpdate();
suTemp = LogMemo->Text;

suTemp += AnsiString((char *)LogMemoBufPtr->Memory, LogMemoBufPtr->Size);
LogMemo->Text = suTemp;
LogMemo->GoToTextEnd();
LogMemoBufPtr->Clear();
LogMemo->Lines->EndUpdate();
```

Comment: Your solution can make the memo displayed correctly but the performance/update speed is still slow. Every time it repeated to display all text including existing text and that caused slow update in memo. I tried to use "Append" but it's still the same performance (slow).

Comment: What is the typical size of your `LogMemoBufPtr` buffer ?

Comment: When adding a string of more than 25000 characters, I don't see performance difference between VCL and FMX software.

Comment: That depends. Sometimes, it got about around 10000 and sometimes, it got around 2000. I did see the difference if final data size is around 50K bytes.

Comment: Step 1 of Solution 1 is better handled by just saving the value of the `Text` property, no need to select the text first: `System::UnicodeString suTemp = LogMemo->Text;` Step 2 is simplify by using the `Length` of the temp `UnicodeString` instead of reading the `Text` again: `LogMemo->SelLength = suTemp.Length();`

Answer (score 0):

`TMemo` in FireMonkey has a [`GoToTextEnd()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Memo.TCustomMemo.GoToTextEnd) method:

> Moves the cursor to the end of the text in the memo control.

You can't use `AnsiString` in mobile platforms (without a [compiler patch](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/2015/09/byte-strings-for-delphi-10-seattles-mobile-compilers/)), nor should you anyway since `TMemo` holds Unicode text (same as VCL's `TMemo` in Delphi 2009 and later).  If your `TMemoryStream` contains 8bit characters, you need to convert them to Unicode, such as with [`TEncoding`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TEncoding), before appending them to the `TMemo`. The [`TEncoding::GetString()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TEncoding.GetString) methods take a `TBytes` as input, so you could use [`TBytesStream`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TBytesStream) instead of `TMemoryStream`.  `TBytesStream` wraps a `TBytes` and has a public [`Bytes`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TBytesStream.Bytes) property.

Try something like this:

```
LogMemo->Lines->BeginUpdate();
try
{
    LogMemo->GoToTextEnd();
    LogMemo->SelLength = 0;
    LogMemo->SelText = TEncoding::Default->GetString(LogMemoBufPtr->Bytes, 0, LogMemoBufPtr->Size);
    /* or:
    TEncoding *enc = TEncoding::GetEncoding(L"desired charset here");
    try {
        LogMemo->SelText = enc->GetString(LogMemoBufPtr->Bytes, 0, LogMemoBufPtr->Size);
    }
    __finally {
        delete enc;
    }
    */
    LogMemo->GoToTextEnd();
    LogMemo->SelLength = 0;
    // not sure if this is the best replacement for EM_SCROLLCARET...
    LogMemo->VScrollBar->Value = LogMemo->VScrollBar->Max;
}
__finally {
    LogMemo->Lines->EndUpdate();
}
```

---

**Update**: I didn't realize that `SelText` is **read-only** in FireMonkey, unlike in VCL. In that case, you have no choice but to append to the `Text` property, which is not as efficient, especially for large text.

```
LogMemo->Lines->BeginUpdate();
try
{
    LogMemo->Text = LogMemo->Text + TEncoding::Default->GetString(LogMemoBufPtr->Bytes, 0, LogMemoBufPtr->Size);
    /* or:
    TEncoding *enc = TEncoding::GetEncoding(L"desired charset here");
    try {
        LogMemo->Text = LogMemo->Text + enc->GetString(LogMemoBufPtr->Bytes, 0, LogMemoBufPtr->Size);
    }
    __finally {
        delete enc;
    }
    */
    LogMemo->GoToTextEnd();
    LogMemo->SelLength = 0;
    // not sure if this is the best replacement for EM_SCROLLCARET...
    LogMemo->VScrollBar->Value = LogMemo->VScrollBar->Max;
}
__finally {
    LogMemo->Lines->EndUpdate();
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the Unicode concept. I will study and change my code to support it. But I still have problem to just write new text to FMX memo component for better performance. "TCustomMemo::SelText"  is not accessible in FMX. So, I need to find another method to write new text only to memo.